# Button click with function having parameters in jasmine unit test(angular)

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am writing unit test in angular for button click event. The button unit test mentioned below works fine for situations where a function is unparameterised -

Like it will work if it is:

`(click)="editForms()"`

but when I add parameters to the functions, like here I have:

`(click)="editForms(array) , the this test fails as - "Failed: Cannot read property 'click' of null" --`

It's not able to call the function `editForms`.

Can anyone please tell me how to do with it?

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyjobsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
     fixture.detectChanges();
  });

    fit('should do editForms button click ', async(() => {
        spyOn(component, 'editForms');
        let button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('button');
        button.click();
        fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
          expect(component.editForms).toHaveBeenCalled();
        })
      }));
```

HTML:

```
 <button mat-raised-button style="background-color:#6666ff;color:white;" (click)="editForms(array)"> <i class="material-icons">create</i></button>
```

component.ts:

```
editForms(name) {
    console.log(name);
    console.log( this.totalJobData);
    for(let e = 0; e < this.totalJobData.length; e++){
      if(this.totalJobData[e].jobName === name){
        this.jobID = this.totalJobData[e].jobId;
        this.sourceCode = this.totalJobData[e].sourceCode;
      }`enter code here`
    }
    console.log(this.sourceCode);
.....
```

Comment: Don't know your use case (and what is `array` supposed to mean here) but I usually use two way binding with `[(ngModel)]` so that I don't have to pass an argument inside the `(click)` event. Then in my unit tests I just do this: `button.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'))`

Comment: 'array' is just a parameter inside function "editForms" and is getting value from                         <tr *ngFor="let array of jobNames | filter : searchText | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: a , id: 'first'}" value="array">
        <td colspan="3">
            {{array}}
        </td>
        <td *ngIf="(jobNames | filter : searchText).length === 0">No matching elements</td>
        <td>  ,    and I can't edit my component.ts,as it is coming from other team, I can just edit my spec file to write test cases.